# Tagged question and perfect tense

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, verbs, tenses, question-tags

I've just passed one of numerous English grammar online tests. And I agree with all the mistakes I've made except  this one:

> You ______ put it back before the boss comes back, won't you?
>
> 1. will have
> 2. won't have
> 3. will
> 4. have

The system has marked my answer 3 as incorrect, and 1 as correct.

And I'm still confused about it, the phrase with 1 makes no sense for me.

So — is 1 really the correct answer? If so — why is it, and not 3?

Comment: You are correct — 3 is the right answer.

Comment: @David Wallace: great, thanks! PS: hi from welly )) PPS: could you please put it as an answer

Comment: I couldn't possibly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Strictly speaking all the first three *could* be considered "valid" (although #2 would be a somewhat contrived context, and would require the final "tag question" to be reversed into "..., will you?").

So I'd say this "online grammar test" is very poor quality, purely on the grounds that there's no single correct answer. All we can say for sure is #4 is a no-hoper.

But let's face it — any half-alert native speaker wouldn't come out with that clumsy repetition of "back" either. If it makes OP feel any better, #3 is actually closest to the more natural phrasing...

> You *will* [make sure you] put it back before the boss returns, won't you?

---

For what it's worth, there is a difference in some contexts (not this one) between using [future perfect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Future_perfect) *(will have done)* and [simple future](http://www.englishpage.com/verbpage/simplefuture.html) *(will do)*...

> When I leave the office I *will enjoy/will have enjoyed* a few hours of leisurely relaxation.

Comment: Assuming #1 (will have) could be a valid answer - shouldn't the tag part be changed to "*won't you have*" then?

Comment: @zerkms: Definitely not

Comment: @zerkms: Certainly, yes.

Comment: @FumbleFingers- I think only *will* is possible. Putting the other two could make the *tag question* part somewhat unorthodox, right?

Comment: @Noah: You're right re #2 - the "tag question" would need to be reversed into *"will you?"*. I'll edit to reflect that.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: and what about http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/73318/tagged-question-and-perfect-tense/73319#comment141951_73319? Should we change the tag question part for #1?

Comment: @zerkms: I don't know what question you *meant* to link there, but you actually linked back to this one. Anyway, if you're thinking that the tag question in #1 should be *"won't you **have**"* then the answer is no - for most speakers, that would be considered unbearably clumsy. Plain *will you/won't you* serves well enough.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I linked to my first comment (the one that starts with "Assuming #1..." :-) Well, thanks for your help

Comment: Maybe it's a regionalism, but I don't find "won't you have" too clumsy.  I would say it quite quickly - almost as if it were spelt "won't you've".  More likely though, if I wanted the meaning of option 1, I'd just say "You will have put it back before the boss comes back, right?"

Comment: @David Wallace: I'm not sure that rings true. You don't find "won't you have" too clumsy, but you wouldn't say it yourself anyway. Sounds to me like you're effectively *avoiding* it, right? :) Personally, I think "right?" doesn't work so well as a *negative* tag question (it replaces *will you?* better than "won't you?").